# Invite links infinite loop on Edge but work on Chrome

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-static-web-app

Hey so when inviting users to our internal site, they are usually redirected from styled auth page auth/login then to .auth/* then to the site once verified. However, the invite link loops this process on Microsoft Edge but works fine on chrome... Is there any reason why it doesnt work on Edge as well? Not sure what information to provide to help with assisting but let me know so I can follow up

I've tried clearing cache and using incognito as well as with different email domains but to no avail

Comment: Is the site/domain you're connecting to configured in a security zone under internet options somewhere? Or maybe configured to be displayed in IE mode or something?